# Displaying html5 content in c++ WebBrowser control

Tags: visual-c++, internet-explorer-9, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to load html5 (built with bootstrap) page in c++ app, using standart WebBrowser control, first few seconds it looks like in the normal browser, then it switch to look like ie8 mode.

FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION is set correct, doctype set correct too. 
Using native ie9 browser, all looks fine.

How to make it to display content correct in WebBrowser component?

OS: Win7x32sp1, ie9, ms visual c++ 2008

Answer (score 0):

To instruct the webbrowser control to render your page as HTML5 you need to add the  tag at the beginning of your file as follows:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<!-- rest of the page content -->
</html>
```

Comment: Of course I add it, and using native ie 9 it looks normally, but in WebBrowser control it doesn't work without <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />, when I add this string, all works fine.